# Creating new tags on Stack Overflow mobile

Tags: support, tags, mobile-web, tag-creation-process

Why am I not allowed to create new tags on the mobile site of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Cross meta dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/why-cant-i-create-a-new-tag-in-mobile

Answer (score 6):

Combining and redacted the answer provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109064/158100) from [waiwai933](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/89334/waiwai933) and the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/why-cant-i-create-a-new-tag-in-mobile#comment281533_109064) from [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose)

> Because it's really easy to make a typo when using a mobile browser, and you don't want to clutter the tag-space with misspellings, so it's prompting you to recheck.
>
> It's very rare that a new tag is intentionally and correctly created, and mobile device auto correct and difficulty typing makes it even more likely that tags are accidentally created. Stack Exchange decide to just disallowed it altogether accordingly.
>
> For legitimate cases, just edit the tag in later when you're not using a mobile browser or switch to the full-site version.

Comment: It would be nice if they could add an explanation in the app - that way people won't think it's a bug.

Comment: @cullub sure, but given the limited resources and focus on other projects I don't think this specific issue will be addressed soon.